# Quickest way to check if 2 arrays contain same values in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

Is there a quicker or more efficient way to check that two arrays contain the same values in javascript?

Here is what I'm currently doing to check this. It works, but is lengthy.

```
    var arraysAreDifferent = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
      if (!array2.includes(array1[i])) {
        arraysAreDifferent = true;
      }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
      if (!array1.includes(array2[i])) {
        arraysAreDifferent = true;
      }
    }
```

Comment: If you need to support old IE and/or are a sociopath you can cast to strings and compare: `console.log(JSON.stringify(['a','b','c'].sort()) === JSON.stringify(['b','c','a'].sort())); // true`

Comment: @Gavin Thanks for the _sociopath_ comment that made me laugh :) However, from what I understand, OP would want `[0,1,1]` and `[0,1]` to pass the test

Comment: An issue with `.sort` is that it's computationally complex - `O(n log n)`, which is worse than `O(n)`

Comment: @Gavin just a note - that "or" is not exclusive. In fact, either of these could lead to the other.

Comment: Highly suggested: [see georg's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58626840/3689450) which uses set operations.

Answer (score 4):

To reduce computational complexity from `O(n ^ 2)` to `O(n)`, use Sets instead - `Set.has` is `O(1)`, but `Array.includes` is `O(n)`.

Rather than a regular `for` loop's verbose manual iteration, use `.every` to check if every item in an array passes a test. Also check that both Set's sizes are the same - if that's done, then if one of the arrays is iterated over, there's no need to iterate over the other (other than for the construction of its Set):

```
const arr1Set = new Set(array1);
const arr2Set = new Set(array2);
const arraysAreDifferent = (
  arr1Set.size === arr2Set.size &&
  array1.every(item => arr2Set.has(item))

);
```

Comment: For pure speed, we don't even need two sets. Sure, the overall complexity is still `O(n)` but each set creation is `O(n)` itself. Since only one is really needed only `arr2Set` could be left in, the other removed. With that said, I do like using two sets - it makes the problem more generic and can thus be expanded to cover more things using set algebra.

Comment: I think both arrays will have to be iterated over at least once regardless, to make sure that each of their elements is contained in the other, and for the computational complexity improvement, one of them needs to be iterated over *again* after that. `arr1Set.size === arr2Set.size` works, but `array1.length === arr2Set.size` won't, due to duplicate items of the same value, or due to additional items not contained in the other array (but the other array has duplicate items)

Answer (score 0):

```
function same(arr1, arr2){
    //----if you want to check by length as well 
    // if(arr1.length != arr2.length){
    //     return false;
    // }

    // creating an object with key => arr1 value and value => number of time that value repeat;
    let frequencyCounter1 = {};
    let frequencyCounter2 = {};
    for(let val of arr1){
        frequencyCounter1[val] = (frequencyCounter1[val] || 0) + 1;
    }
    for(let val of arr2){
        frequencyCounter2[val] = (frequencyCounter2[val] || 0) + 1;
    }
    for(let key in frequencyCounter1){
        //check if the key is present in arr2 or not 
        if(!(key in frequencyCounter2)) return false;
        //check the number of times the value repetiton is same or not;
        if(frequencyCounter2[key]!==frequencyCounter1[key]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```