# How to find differences between the first array and the second

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

I have 2 arrays and a method that finds differences.
But at the moment, the method shows the result of the difference between both arrays.
How to implement comparisons of the first array with the second so that only the differences of the first array are returned.

```js
let test1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4/2', '5/4', '6-2'];
let test2 = ['1', '2', '3', '5/4', '4/2', '6-1', '7/2', '8-2'];


const diff = function (arr1, arr2) {
    return arr1.filter(i => !arr2.includes(i)).concat(arr2.filter(i => !arr1.includes(i)))
}

console.log(diff(test1, test2));
```

Expected to return a value: 6-2

Comment: Also relevant: [this answer that defines set operations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58626840/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put all the numbers of 2nd array in a `Set` and then use `.filter()` method on the first array to filter those elements of 1st array that are not present in the `Set`.

```js
let test1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4/2', '5/4', '6-2'];
let test2 = ['1', '2', '3', '5/4', '4/2', '6-1', '7/2', '8-2'];


const diff = function(arr1, arr2) {
  const set = new Set(arr2);
  return arr1.filter(n => !set.has(n));
}

console.log(diff(test1, test2));
```

**Note:** You could also use `!arr2.includes(n)` condition in the `filter()` method but then for each number in `arr1`, we will go through each element in `arr2` which is not ideal. Using a `Set`, we don't have to check each element in `arr2`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to filter on the first array all elements which are not in the second array so :

```js
const test1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4/2', '5/4', '6-2'];
const test2 = ['1', '2', '3', '5/4', '4/2', '6-1', '7/2', '8-2'];

const differences = test1.filter(o => !test2.includes(o));

console.log(differences);
```